# Setting browserAction icon in a concrete Chrome window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons, browser-action

I want to set different browserAction icons in different windows. The only method I found for this is:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon

But it doesn't take a context. It changes icon in every window. I know it is somehow possible, because adBlock do this. Do anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution, I hope it will be helpful:

```
function setIcon(state, getIconNameCallback) {

    // we need to set the icon globally first, 
    // to avoid blinking to default icon

    chrome.windows.getLastFocused(null, function(window) {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                'path': getIconNameCallback(state, tab.url)
            });
        });
    });

    // then we must set the icon for each tab,
    // without that the extension wont behave
    // properly with multiple windows

    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
                'path': getIconNameCallback(state, tabs[i].url), 
                'tabId': tabs[i].id
            });
        }
    });

}
```